# Вывести числа согласно образцу используя цикл While

Tags: python, while

Нужна помощь, необходимо вывести числа в определенном порядке. Может быть это очень просто, но я весь день не понимаю как доделать код...Спасибо...
Например:

Введите число: 5

1

5

2

4

3

или

Введите число: 6

1

6

2

5

3

4

Мой код:

```
a = int(input("Введите Число: "))
i = 0
while(i< a):
   print(i+1)
   print(a-i)
   i+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно добавить условие с досрочным завершение цикла, чтобы числа не выводились дальше, но нам надо понимать, если число нечетно то нам надо вывести медиану, а если нет, значит мы уже все вывели

```
a = int(input("Введите Число: "))
i = 0
while(i< a):
   if (a-i<=i+1):
      if a%2==1: print(i+1)
      break
   print(i+1)
   print(a-i)
   i+=1
```